# Android sqlite and SaxParser

Tags: android, sqlite, saxparser

at the moment I am a bit confused. I receive an XML file and want to store that content in a sqlite db. Sounds very common I guess. I have a DBAdapter which basically does the following

```
private  static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    private final Context ctx;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, Constants.DB_NAME, null, Constants.DB_VERSION);
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL("create table mytable (_id integer primary key autoincrement, field text not null, field2 text not null );");
        fillDb(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
    //not relevant here so skip it
    }

    private void fillDb(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        InputStream rawInput = this.ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try
        {
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            saxParser.parse(rawInput, new HandlerXmlData());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        //not relevant here so skip it              
        }


     //this manual entries would work here
        //ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put("field", "aaa");
        //values.put("field2", "bbb");
        //db.insert("mytable", null, values);
                }
```

The problem is now that within my SAXParser

public class HandlerXmlData extends DefaultHandler 
{

```
private String currentValue = "";

public void startDocument()
{

}

public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) 
{
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
{
    currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
    //here I get the value from my XML
              //so I need something like db.insert(...)
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
{

}
```

So within my SAXParser I cannot access the db object I have in my DatabaseHelper class. how do I bring these together?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you pass the db object to the parser through constructor?

```
public HandlerXmlData(SQLiteDatabase db){
    this.db = db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options to achieve what you are trying to do.

1. You could simply pass in the SQLiteDatabase object into your HandlerXmlData object, keep the object as an instance variable, and insert into it as you approach your values.
2. You could also create a bean representing your database model.  Within your HandlerXmlData object, you could have an instance variable storing a collection of this bean, and add to it as you receive the sax events.  When the parsing is done, you should have a method from which you can access the populated model, iterate over it and insert each entry into your database.